# Substr for array in preg_replace

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I want to trim ** from text. If content include `**text**` - than is **bold**

```
$find = array('/\*\*(.*)\*\*/', '/@(\\w+)/');
$replace = array('<span style="font-weight:bold">$0</span>', '<a href=/profile/$1>@$1</a>');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);
```

but now it looks like: ** **bold** **

Comment: Change `$0` to `$1` in `$replace[0]`. You get what you get, because `$0` refers to the text matched by the whole pattern, not just part in `()`

Comment: Don't use preg_replace for HTML tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$0` by `$1` in your replace array:

```
$replace = array('<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>', '<a href=/profile/$1>@$1</a>');
//                                        here __^^
```

You'd better use the following instead of a greedy match:

```
$find = array('/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/', '/@(\\w+)/');
```

Comment: No, my code is working fine.  $0 is **bold** and $1 is @username. I just want to TRIM -> **

Comment: @Szmerd: `$0` contains the whole match (ie. `**text**`) and `$1` contains the first group (ie: `text`).